# Objective-J Cappuccino want a list of buttons on main menu, when I click the panel refreshes with UI of button selected

Tags: cappuccino, objective-j

Dear all, I am new to objective-j/c and cappuccino not really sure how this all fits together.

The code below is taken from http://github.com/jfahrenkrug/CappuccinoLocations1
What I need to do is:

I need a landing main menu which is a CPView called ie MainView with five or so buttons, when you click on the LocationButton on MainView is replaces MainView by with LocationView, which displays the contents of jfahrenkrug's work. A similar effect will happen with each other button.

What is the correct Objective-c/j way of handling this approach?

```
@import <Foundation/CPObject.j>
@import "src/Location/LocationView.j"

@implementation AppController : CPObject
{
  LocationView locationView;
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(CPNotification)aNotification
{
    var theWindow = [[CPWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:CGRectMakeZero()          styleMask:CPBorderlessBridgeWindowMask],
      mainContentView = [theWindow locationView],
      bounds = [locationView bounds];


[mainContentView setBackgroundColor:[CPColor colorWithRed:212.0 /255.0 green:221.0/ 255.0 blue:230.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];

locationView = [[LocationView alloc]    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,920.0,590.0)];
[locationView setCenter:[mainContentView center]];
[locationView setBackgroundColor:[CPColor whiteColor]]
[locationView setAutoresizingMask:CPViewMinXMargin | CPViewMaxXMargin |     CPViewMinYMargin | CPViewMaxYMargin];

var shadow = [[CPShadowView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMakeZero()];
[shadow setFrameForContentFrame:[locationView frame]];
[shadow setAutoresizingMask:CPViewMinXMargin | CPViewMaxXMargin | CPViewMinYMargin | CPViewMaxYMargin];
[mainContentView addSubview:shadow];
[mainContentView addSubview:locationView];

[theWindow orderFront:self];

}
```

Now we have the locationView.j

```
@import "LocationsController.j"
@import "LocationListView.j"
@import "MapController.j"
@import "LocationsToolbar.j"
@import "LocationDetailView.j"
@import "LocationDetailController.j"

@implementation LocationView : CPView
{
  LocationsController locationsController;
  LocationListView locationListView;
  MapController mapController;
  MKMapView mapView;
  CPTextField coordinatesLabel;
  LocationsToolbar locationsToolbar;
  LocationDetailView locationDetailView;
  LocationDetailController locationDetailController;
  CPTextField searchField;

  //  id delegate @accessors;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aFrame
{
  self = [super initWithFrame:aFrame];
  if(self){

    locationsController = [[LocationsController alloc] init];
    [locationsController loadExampleLocations];

    locationListView = [[LocationListView alloc]    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,226.0,400.0)];
    [locationListView setContent:[locationsController locations]];
    [locationListView setDelegate:locationsController];
    [locationsController setLocationListView:locationListView];

    var locationScrollView = [[CPScrollView alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0,65.0,243.0,400.0)];
    [locationScrollView setDocumentView:locationListView];
    [locationScrollView setAutohidesScrollers:YES];
    [[locationScrollView self] setBackgroundColor:[CPColor whiteColor]];
    [self addSubview:locationScrollView];

    mapController = [[MapController alloc] init];

    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(510,65,400,400) apiKey:''     ];
    [mapView setDelegate:self];
    mapController.mapView = mapView;
    [self addSubview:mapView];

    coordinatesLabel = [[CPTextField alloc]     initWithFrame:CGRectMake(510,465,200,35)];
    [coordinatesLabel setTextColor:[CPColor colorWithHexString:@"009900"]];
    [coordinatesLabel setFont:[CPFont systemFontOfSize:14.0]];
    [coordinatesLabel setEditable:NO];
    [coordinatesLabel setStringValue:@"-/-"];
    [mapController setCoordinatesLabel:coordinatesLabel];
    [self addSubview:coordinatesLabel];

    locationsToolbar = [[LocationsToolbar alloc]    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0,467.0,226.0,25.0)];
    [locationsToolbar setDelegate:locationsController];
    [self addSubview:locationsToolbar];

    locationDetailController = [[LocationDetailController alloc] init];
    locationDetailController.mapController = mapController;
    locationsController.locationDetailController = locationDetailController;
    [mapController setDelegate:locationDetailController];

    locationDetailView = [[LocationDetailView alloc]    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(510,490,400,90)];
    [locationDetailView setDelegate:locationDetailController];
    [locationDetailController setLocationDetailView:locationDetailView];
    [self addSubview:locationDetailView];

    searchField = [CPTextField roundedTextFieldWithStringValue:@""  placeholder:@"Location" width:200.0];
    [searchField setFrameOrigin:CGPointMake(510.0,35.0)];
    [searchField setDelegate:self];
    [self addSubview:searchField];

    var searchButton = [[CPButton alloc]    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(710.0,37.0,60.0,24.0)];
    [searchButton setTitle:"Search"];
    [searchButton setTarget:self];
    [searchButton setAction:@selector(searchLocation)];
    [self addSubview:searchButton];

  }
  return self;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question but essentially a window has a default view called the content view. You get it like so:

```
var contentView = [theWindow contentView];
```

To the content view you can add subviews (and buttons).

```
[contentView addSubview:myLocationView];
```

The location of those subviews is determined by the 'frame' of the subview.

```
[myLocationView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100)];
```

You can replace the content view's subviews with something else by either removing the previous views or using the setSubviews message.

```
[contentView setSubviews:[aButton, anotherButton]];
```

So essentially if you want to swap out one view for another, call 'setSubviews' on its super view with the new views you want. Hope that helps to get you started.

Comment: sadly winging it is not working, I've got myself an objective-c book and studying this language and API. Though your response did indeed help! thnx ( http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/ObjC.pdf )

Comment: turned out to be a browser incompatibility problem - works well on safari